# Outdoor lights stay on

Tags: electrical, timer

Been using GE Digital Timer Model 15313.
I replaced outdoor lights with 40 Watt equivalent LED bulbs, lights were flickering. shut timer off. Turned on timer and lights came on(all okay so far.) Reprogramed timer, lights were on when they weren't supposed to be on... Pressed manual on/off, lights stayed stayed on. I have wiring and programing instructions, checked and rechecked everything, but not sure if its the manual on/ff button or the LED bulbs with the older timer. Any ideas?

Comment: That switch may not be compatible with LED bulbs.  In fact, the instructions say "Not for use with CFL or fluorescent bulbs. Use with incandescent, xenon, halogen."

Comment: Do you still have the old lights?  If you do try them on the timer to see if the timer still works right.  LEDs might not like to be changed with the power on.

Comment: Is there a neutral wire available in the junction box where the timer is installed?

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic problem. Any smart device - timer, WiFi or other wireless controllable switch, motion sensor, etc. - needs to get power for itself. (Well, almost any. There are purely mechanical timers available, but generally they are "turn to set how long it stays on" and not "program in advance for repeated daily use".)

There are several ways to get power, including:

- Get a little power through the lighting (load) circuit, even when "off". This works great with incandescent lights. It does not work well, if at all, with fluorescent or LED lights. Depending on the amount of power needed and the particular lights, you can end up with: lights on, lights dim, lights flickering or timer/etc. simply not work at all. **This is your current situation.** See the [manual page](https://www.manualsdir.com/manuals/400625/ge-15313-ge-7-day-in-wall-digital-timer.html) for a diagram which shows that this timer is wired exactly that way. The manual also says "*Not for use with CFL or fluorescent bulbs. Use with incandescent, xenon, halogen.*" LEDs aren't even mentioned because they were not so common back in 2011.
- Connect to neutral. This is the *best* way to do things. Unfortunately, many older homes (like many switched lights in my home) are wired with *switch loops*. A switch loop has just two wires (plus ground unless very old), and those wires are used for hot/line (incoming power) and switched hot/load (power to the light). A neutral wire can be added if you have conduit, but otherwise you need to run a whole new cable to get neutral. As a result, the current NEC requires neutral in most switch boxes to solve this problem. You *may* have neutral in your switch box, in which case changing to this method is preferred. Open the box and remove the switch. If you have a bundle of at least two white wires together, and no white wire to the switch, then you have neutral available and can use it by adding another wire to the neutral bundle.
- Battery. This used to be fairly common, but has the drawback that you have to change batteries every so often.
- Ground. This is allowed in *limited* circumstances. Where it is allowed, the manual will make it very clear that ground is **required**, which is not generally the case for switches - recommended normally but not absolutely required. In particular, some switches will actually recommend neutral but include wiring instructions that clearly connect one wire to neutral if available and to ground if neutral is not available. **While almost any "neutral required" device would actually work connected to ground, this is only allowed under very limited circumstances where very little current is required.**

So open up the switch box. If you have neutral, get a modern "neutral required" timer that also specifically says it works with LED lighting. If you don't have neutral, look for a switch that can legitimately work with ground or that uses a battery. Unfortunately, in a quick search right now the only "no neutral required" programmable timer I could found uses a battery.